# How would you describe the difference between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar

The block has a mass of 50 kg.
The mass of the block is 50 kg.

Comment: The first sentence emphasies "block" and the second, "mass".

Comment: A techie would describe the difference as "Hamming distance".

Comment: The first sentence is transitive and the second one is intransitive. For one thing. There are lots of other differences.

Comment: Is "to be" considered intransitive?